# How to properly rewrite php code from version 5.6 to 7.x?

Tags: php

I tied it myself but it does not work for me. How to properly change for example this old code to be compatible with php 7.x?

```
class DbSimple_Generic
{
    function& connect($dsn)
    {
        // Load database driver and create its instance.
        $parsed = DbSimple_Generic::parseDSN($dsn);
        if (!$parsed) {
            $dummy = null;
            return $dummy;
        }
        $class = 'DbSimple_'.ucfirst($parsed['scheme']);
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            $file = str_replace('_', '/', $class) . ".php";
            if ($f = @fopen($file, "r", true)) {
                fclose($f);
                require_once($file);
            } else {
                $base = basename($file);
                $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
                if (@is_file($path = "$dir/$base")) {
                    require_once($path);
                } else {
                    trigger_error("Error loading database driver: no file $file in include_path; no file $base in $dir", E_USER_ERROR);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        $object =& new $class($parsed);   
        if (isset($parsed['ident_prefix'])) {
            $object->setIdentPrefix($parsed['ident_prefix']);
        }



class DbSimple_Mysql_Blob extends DbSimple_Generic_Blob
{
    var $blobdata = null;
    var $curSeek = 0;

    function DbSimple_Mysql_Blob(&$database, $blobdata=null)
    {
        $this->blobdata = $blobdata;
        $this->curSeek = 0;
    }

    function read($len)
    {
        $p = $this->curSeek;
        $this->curSeek = min($this->curSeek + $len, strlen($this->blobdata));
        return substr($this->blobdata, $this->curSeek, $len);
    }

    function write($data)
    {
        $this->blobdata .= $data;
    }

    function close()
    {
        return $this->blobdata;
    }

    function length()
    {
        return strlen($this->blobdata);
    }
}        

function& _performNewBlob($blobid=null)
{
    $obj =& new DbSimple_Mysql_Blob($this, $blobid);
    return $obj;
}
```

I tried to use every possible way to make this work like this:

```
$object = new $class($parsed);
$object->method();
```

Becase it seems for PHP 7.x is this the most problematic part:

```
$object =& new $class($parsed);
```

But thisdid not work. I tried to find it on some PHP documentation but no luck so far. So how to properly rewrite this? Thank you

Using this on Ubuntu Server 64bit 16.04+ with Apache and mysql.

Comment: Do you have any errors in logs? Any unexpected behaviour?

Comment: This `$object =& new` can changed to `$object = new` becuase Objects are always references in PHP>=5! `function& connect($dsn)` - is this documented anywhere?

Comment: `function DbSimple_Mysql_Blob(&$database, $blobdata=null) // &$database is not used in that function so that could be cleaned!`

Comment: As note:  Error by `function& xyz(){}` can be  `Only variable references should be returned by reference`,   but this is so oldschool never seen it in my coding life :-) So try to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is a better idea to understand that function and rewrite in a cleaner way but please find below my changes, hopefully it helps.

```
class DbSimple_Generic
{
    function connect($dsn)
    {
        // Load database driver and create its instance.
        $parsed = DbSimple_Generic::parseDSN($dsn);
        if (!$parsed) {
            $dummy = null;
            return $dummy;
        }
        $class = 'DbSimple_'.ucfirst($parsed['scheme']);
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            $file = str_replace('_', '/', $class) . ".php";
            if ($f = @fopen($file, "r", true)) {
                fclose($f);
                require_once($file);
            } else {
                $base = basename($file);
                $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
                if (@is_file($path = "$dir/$base")) {
                    require_once($path);
                } else {
                    trigger_error("Error loading database driver: no file $file in include_path; no file $base in $dir", E_USER_ERROR);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        $object = new $class($parsed);   
        if (isset($parsed['ident_prefix'])) {
            $object->setIdentPrefix($parsed['ident_prefix']);
        }
    }      
    public static function parseDSN($dsn){ // public or private depends on what you intend to do
       // implementation here...  
    }

    public function setIdentPrefix($identPrefix){
       // implementation here...
    }
}

class DbSimple_Mysql_Blob extends DbSimple_Generic_Blob
{
    var $blobdata = null;
    var $curSeek = 0;

    function __construct($blobdata=null)  // use __construct for class constructor
    {
        $this->blobdata = $blobdata;
        $this->curSeek = 0;
    }

    function read($len)
    {
        $p = $this->curSeek;
        $this->curSeek = min($this->curSeek + $len, strlen($this->blobdata));
        return substr($this->blobdata, $this->curSeek, $len);
    }

    function write($data)
    {
        $this->blobdata .= $data;
    }

    function close()
    {
        return $this->blobdata;
    }

    function length()
    {
        return strlen($this->blobdata);
    }
}        

function _performNewBlob($blobid=null)
{
    $obj = new DbSimple_Mysql_Blob($blobid); // no need to use &
    return $obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't ever use `=&` operator. It's been useless since PHP 5.0 and removed in PHP 7.0:

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.new-by-ref

You will find more things on that page that no longer work in PHP 7.

Comment: SO I will just use '=' Is that it?

Comment: Yes. `$object = new $class($parsed);` has been the only right way for like 10 years now.